# Must group to Aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Is it a requirement that you have to group by something in your select if aggregating such as using SUM?  That you must have a group by clause?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: I suppose you could get weird with sub-queries or something to prove a point - but typically yes.  (unless of course you want the sum of every single record returned by the query)

Answer (score 6):

No it is not a requirement.

Aggregates without a `GROUP BY` are Scalar aggregates and always return exactly one row.

**Example**

```
SELECT SUM(high)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Aggregates with a `GROUP BY` are Vector aggregates and return zero or one row per group.

**Example**

```
SELECT [type], SUM(high)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 1 = 0
GROUP BY [type]
```

Comment: +1 Actually, aggregating always implies grouping. It's just that if `GROUP BY` is omitted (which it may indeed), then `GROUP BY ()` is implied.

Comment: @AndriyM - Interesting point. `SELECT SUM(high) FROM master..spt_values WHERE 1 = 0 GROUP BY ()` returns no rows. Without the `GROUP BY()` returns one row so they are not equivalent.

Comment: Something to ponder over. It does work without `WHERE 1=0`, though. I wonder if this has ever been asked about...

Comment: Well, so far my conclusion is that actual (or, should I say, *explicit*) `GROUP BY ()` doesn't return rows on empty datasets. In all other cases the results with `GROUP BY ()` seem to be exactly the same as those produced by identical queries with no `GROUP BY` clause. Even if it eventually proves the only difference, it's sufficient enough to take my words (expressed in the first comment) back.